# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am unable to find answer through the following links

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214853/spring-jersey-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-application-getpro)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30723370/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-application-getpropertiesljava-u)
[Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225618/java-restfull-webservice-jax-rs-implementation-with-jersey-2-3-1-libraries)

Following is my pom.xml dependency

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.41</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency> 
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet/mimepull -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>mimepull</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
            
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
           
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
          
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.searchbox/jest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>oro</groupId>
        <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
   
</dependencies>
```

I have also gone through my `~/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api` directory, but it contains only one directory `2.0.1`.

I am not able to understand the problem.

I am using Tomcat 8.

Stacktrace

```
19-Jul-2017 14:14:37.425 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
19-Jul-2017 14:14:37.425 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
19-Jul-2017 14:14:40.784 SEVERE [http-nio-8083-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4944)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1493)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:884)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Post complete stacktrace.

Comment: Try deleting `~/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api` directory. It must not be the true dependency.

Comment: I have tried that , I have deleted ws directory and then rebuild my project , still I am facing the same issues.

Comment: There should be another dependency on your classpath which is overriding `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`. Are you using Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

The [`Application#getProperties()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getProperties--) method was introduced in JAX-RS 2.0. And this error typically happens when you mix JAX-RS 1.x and JAX-RS 2.x.

So check the JARs on your classpath and remove everything that relates to JAX-RS 1.x (and Jersey 1.x).

Once you are using Maven, you can run [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) and check what's going on with your dependencies.

---

I also see a few things that may cause some headaches:

1. See below the correct [Servlet API](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/) dependency for Tomcat 8 (don't forget the `provided` scope):

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.1</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Ensure that all Jersey dependencies use the same version.
3. You probably don't need the `javax.ws.rs-api`, `jersey-server` and `jersey-common` dependencies.

   - Use `jersey-container-servlet`, `jersey-media-json-jackson` and `jersey-media-multipart` dependencies.
   - The [`jersey-container-servlet`](https://jersey.github.io/project-info/2.26-b08/jersey/project/jersey-container-servlet/dependencies.html) dependency uses `javax.ws.rs-api`,
     `jersey-server` and `jersey-common` as transitive dependencies.
4. You probably don't need `<type>jar</type>` in your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. I had similar  issue on a centos 7.x for Zeppelin 0.8.1  installation. Was going crazy as it was ok on my MAC. I detected I had the conflict versions 1.9 and 2.x of jersery* api and dependencies. My Dirty workaround was to unset CLASSPATH and allow the jersery* version of Zeppelin take effect. Probably check later the Zeppelin configuration to modify the CLASSPATH settings to have ZEPPELIN lib checked first.

Comment: Yeah figured it out with a dirty workaround .  Had to change tje daemon script bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh for line 85 from `CLASSPATH+=":${ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH}"` to `CLASSPATH="${ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH}:${CLASSPATH}"`.

Comment: How do you identify the JAX-RS 1.x (and Jersey) dependencies?

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Scala SBT to build a spark program and get this error when using spark UI. It's weird that the `com.sun.jersey 1.x` was found in dependency. I just remove it and everything works.

Comment: `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar` was the culprit in my `~/.groovy/lib` dir.

Answer (score 9):

It can be solved by excluding the jar as defined below, as JSR jar is conflicting with JAX-RS and creating the above error

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.1</version>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please remove it and run, it worked for me and i hope it will work for u too.

Comment: That's the best solution if the conflict is coming from the jsr311-api included in jdk11.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to write the solution in this topic, cause all the suggestions above didn't help me. I had the same error and used `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` and `resteasy-jackson2-provider`. The first dependency uses jax-rs 1.0, while the second one uses jax-rs 2.0, so this is the reason for the conflict, as I already said. I just refer to the solution, cause it's not mine, but could help you:

[Eureka Client dependency update to Jersey 2.x](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/600)

[Eureka and Jersey 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400766/eureka-and-jersey-2-x)

Solution:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Cassio.  There are a couple of things I would add:

- The dependency for me existed in jersey-core.
- I could only see the hierarchal dependency in mvn dependency:tree.  I may have missed it, but it was not showing up in the Eclipse hierarchy tree view.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this fixed my problem:

Adding this exclusion under the dependency which happens to use a conflicted jsr library in my pom.xml

```
       <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```